# Generating an n length bit list in Python

Tags: python, permutation, bit

I want a function that will give me all the possible strings of a specified length that are composed of only zeros and ones. For example:

```
spam(4)
```

should get me:

```
['0110', '0111', '0001', '0011', '0010', '0101', '0100', '1110', '1100', '1101', '1010', '1011', '1001', '1000']
```

I tried to use `itertools.permutations` for the job. So, this is what I did.

```
def getPerms(n):
    perms = getCandidates(n)
    res = []
    for i in perms:
        res.extend(permutations(i))
    res = clean(res)
    return res

def clean(ar):
    res = []
    for i in ar:
        temp = ""
        for j in i:
            temp += j
        res.append(temp)
    return list(set(res))

def getCandidates(n):
    res = []
    for i in range(1, n):
        res.append("1"*i + "0"*(n-i))
    return res
```

But this is horribly inefficient and gives a Memory Error on 10 as input.

Comment: To be clear -- you want it to contain at least one and at least one zero? Because `0000` and `1111` should be in your set otherwise.

Comment: Yes, I need those possibilities.

Answer (score 8):

Use [`itertools.product`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) instead.

```
>>> import itertools
>>> [''.join(i) for i in itertools.product('01', repeat=4)]
['0000', '0001', '0010', '0011', '0100', '0101', '0110', '0111', '1000', '1001', '1010', '1011', '1100', '1101', '1110', '1111']
```

Using a function (assuming `itertools` has already been imported):

```
def bitGen(n):
    return [''.join(i) for i in itertools.product('01', repeat=n)]
```

For larger `n`s it might be more appropriate to return a generator.

```
def bitGen(n):
    return (''.join(i) for i in itertools.product('01', repeat=n))

# Alternatively:

def bitGen(n):
    for i in itertools.product('01', repeat=n):
        yield ''.join(i)
```

Comment: Or `for i in itertools.product('01', repeat=n): yield ''.join(i)` in the last one.

Comment: I didn't think about using itertools.product(). Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

You just want to generate bit-strings, evidently. Here's the fastest way I know:

```
for i in xrange(1, 2**n-1):
    yield '{:0{n}b}'.format(i, n=n)
```

This generates every bitstring of length exactly `n` containing at least one 1 and one 0.

Example:

```
>>> def gen(n):
...     for i in xrange(1, 2**n-1):
...         yield '{:0{n}b}'.format(i, n=n)
... 
>>> list(gen(4))
['0001', '0010', '0011', '0100', '0101', '0110', '0111', '1000', '1001', '1010', '1011', '1100', '1101', '1110']
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the excellent answers above, if you want to continue down the path you started, here is a better implementation using `yield`:

```
from itertools import permutations

def spam(n):
    for perm in getPerms(n):
        print perm,
    print

def getPerms(n):
    for i in getCandidates(n):
        for perm in set(permutations(i)):
            yield ''.join(perm)

def getCandidates(n):
    for i in range(1, n):
        res = "1" * i + "0" * (n - i)
        yield res

spam(4)
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you could use recursion .. this has the added advantage of being able to generate any n bit k base number

```
def bitStr(numDig, base):
 if numDig == 0: return []
 if numDig == 1: return [str(i) for i in range(0,base)]   
 return [ digit + bits for digit in bitStr(1, base)for bits in bitStr(numDig - 1, base)]
```

print (bitStr(4, 2))

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if range iterators are fastest (specifically, for bit-string lengths that are `powers of 2 themselves - i.e. 2/4/8/16` ):

I'm really bad at `python` and don't know how to properly translate this code to `python`, but the approach is the same :

- **Squaring**, of *anything*, is simply replacing each atomic unit of the entity, with a full copy of the entity

Absolutely nothing says only numbers (or numerically-related concepts) can be "squared" - you can also "*square*" a string or even "square" a binary file :

e.g. *square* "**ABC**" to make "**ABCABCABC**"

Same with bit-strings - from a starting point of "`01`"

- **2** cycles of `while()` loop for every `hex` combo,
- **3** cycles of `while()` loop for every `byte` combo,
- **4** cycles of `while()` loop for every `2-byte` combo,

i.e. every bit-string, `0`-`65535`, pre-sorted in sequential order

50% of that time shown here is already spent on the final formatting step to have its output identical to python's list.

```
( fg && fg && fg ) 2>/dev/null; 
 echo;
( time ( nice mawk2 'BEGIN{ 
               ___+=___=length(_=(_<_)(_~_))
            __="."
      while(___—){
             ____=_;
         gsub(__,"\\&&",____)+gsub(__,____,_)
          __=(__)__ 
      }
      gsub(__,", \47&\47",_); print "["(substr(_,3))"]" 
   }' )) \ 
          \
          | pvE9 |  xxh128sum
 sleep 1;
 ( time ( python3 -c '

      def gen(n):
          for i in range(0,2**n):
              yield "{:0{n}b}".format(i, n=n)

      print(list(gen(16)))' )) | pvE9 | xxh128sum | lgp3

( nice mawk2 ; )  0.01s user 0.00s system 44% cpu **0.017** total

     out9: 1.25MiB 0:00:00 [ 975MiB/s] [ 975MiB/s] [<=> ]

eca41050d85b57229bca0e0ce3828dd8  stdin

( python3 -c ; )  0.05s user 0.01s system 93% cpu **0.065** total

     out9: 1.25MiB 0:00:00 [30.3MiB/s] [30.3MiB/s] [<=> ]

eca41050d85b57229bca0e0ce3828dd8  stdin
```

Even just materializing `python`'s `iterator` into a `list` without even storing it into a variable took `5.364 seconds for 24-bit strings` :

```
( time ( python3 -c '
def gen(n):
    for i in range(0,2**n):
        yield "{:0{n}b}".format(i, n=n)

list(gen(24))' ) ) |lgp3

( python3 -c ; )  5.14s user 0.22s system 99% cpu 5.364 total
```

With the regex approach, one can nearly half the time :

```
echo; ( time ( nice  mawk2 'BEGIN{
   ___+=___=length(_=(_<_)(_~_));__="."
   ___+=___*___+___--;___________=_<_
                 gsub(__,"|&",_)
                      ____=_
     gsub("[|]","\\&",____)
                     srand()
   __=int(1E6*substr(srand(),7))

 while(___--) { gsub("[|][^|]+",____,_) }

 print sprintf(" %10s%.0s%3s :: %12.f :: %10.6f","",
               srand(),23-___,length(_),-(__-int(1E6*substr(\
               srand(),7)))/1E6)
 
 gsub("[|]","\47, \47",_)
 print "\t",length(_) }' ) )  | ecp


  ( nice mawk2 ; )  2.84s user 0.17s system 99% cpu 3.025 total

        24 ::    419430400 ::   2.436281 (secs, just the loops)

                 469762048 (string length after formatting
```

- `...111111111111110100|111111111111111111110101|111111111111111111110110|111111111111111111110111|111111111111111111111000|111111111111111111111001|111111111111111111111010|111111111111111111111011|111111111111111111111100|111111111111111111111101|111111111111111111111110|111111111111111111111111`

`2.44` seconds to materialize all the strings, and another `0.58s` or so to format it more closely to `python`'s `list()`

```
 echo; ( time ( nice  mawk2 'BEGIN{

          ___+=___=length(_=(_<_)(_~_));__="."
          ___+=(___*=___)-3;___________=_<_
         gsub(__,"|&",_);____=_
         gsub("[|]","\\&",____)
         srand()
         __=int(1E6*substr(srand(),7))

  while(___--) {

      gsub("[|][^|]+",____,_)
      print sprintf(" %10s%.0s%3s :: %12.f :: %10.6f",\
                    "",srand(),30-___,length(_),\
                    -(__-int(1E6*substr(srand(),7)))/1E6)
      fflush()

  } }' ) )

         2 ::           12 ::   0.000017
         3 ::           32 ::   0.000046
         4 ::           80 ::   0.000057
         5 ::          192 ::   0.000069
         6 ::          448 ::   0.000082
         7 ::         1024 ::   0.000100
         8 ::         2304 ::   0.000126
         9 ::         5120 ::   0.000176
        10 ::        11264 ::   0.000269
        11 ::        24576 ::   0.000464
        12 ::        53248 ::   0.000955
        13 ::       114688 ::   0.001938
        14 ::       245760 ::   0.003811
        15 ::       524288 ::   0.007272
        16 ::      1114112 ::   0.013748
        17 ::      2359296 ::   0.025983
        18 ::      4980736 ::   0.046584
        19 ::     10485760 ::   0.081964
        20 ::     22020096 ::   0.150606
        21 ::     46137344 ::   0.292735
        22 ::     96468992 ::   1.528053
        23 ::    201326592 ::   1.220281
        24 ::    419430400 ::   2.458899
        25 ::    872415232 ::   5.029643
        26 ::   1811939328 ::  10.303509
        27 ::   3758096384 ::  21.498547
        28 ::   7784628224 ::  45.395313
        29 ::  16106127360 ::  92.187767
        30 ::  33285996544 :: 195.449874

    ( nice mawk2 ; )  
    181.84s user 11.35s system 98% cpu 3:16.37 total
```

For the slower version of this concept, it took `3.25 minutes` to generate 1-billion bit-string combos,

for a final single string spanning exactly `31.00 GB`.

- `from`              `0.`
- `to`  `1,073,741,823.`